# Datatypes and objects shadowed by imports

Tags: vb.net, ide

When I import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (with added com-reference to Excel Object library), it seems to shadow some datatypes and objects. I have to qualify DataTable everywhere to System.Data.DataTable. I did however not find a way to use the Application-object any more at all. I tried My.Application, but that's different (does not have Application.StartupPath for example).
a) Where can I find the Application object, or
b) Is there a way to hint the IDE to use eg. System.Data.DataTable by default when I use DataTable?
(sorry about formats, writing from cell phone)

Comment: my.application is not windows.forms.application ... which contains the property `StartupPath`

Comment: Ah yes thanks, I just didn't find that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the shadowing, I think it's best to simply *not* use the `import` line in any module, but using everything for Excel fully qualified like `Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`. That seems easier to me than having other data types messed up.